# How to configure OSX to not to sort new files in a folder and how to prevent new Finder windows pop-upping when unzipped?

Tags: macos, finder, zip

I have to unzip a bunch of files in a bunch of different folders. So I select one file to unzip, then move onto the next file. But as I set a bunch of files to unzip, they start to complete and start popping up new windows!

Pretty soon my screen is covered with new windows popping up constantly and it becomes a pain to navigate, whether it's to select new files to unzip or do something else.

Secondly, on Windows I've used to have my newly created zip-files to be in the end of the file list, ie. they appear as the last item in the Explorer when viewing the folder's contents.

On OS X, though, the zip-files get sorted automatically, which is not what I'd prefer.

Questions:

- How to configure OS X to append new files in a folder to the end of the folder (regardless of how its sorted)?
- How to configure new folders to not pop up when unzipping has finished?

Comment: Please tone down the Apple bashing. It's an unnecessary narrative. We understand you've having a problem, continuing to lay on your frustration doesn't add anything to the question.

Comment: Background info was a bit confusing, but the real question is fine — although it could be two questions rather than one for easier discoverability and answerability.

Comment: Wow this is not at all what I said. 0.!

Comment: So the real question is, since there are two questions, and two people answered one each, who gets the accept? :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Archive Utility can be lightly configured. The easy way to do it is to open an archive file and as soon as you see a progress dialog, hit <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> in order to bring up the app preferences.

Otherwise, you can manually open the Archive Utility alone by browsing to `/System/Library/CoreServices` and opening `Archive Utility.app`. Afterwards, you can use the Archive Utility menu to get to the preferences, or again use <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open the app's preferences up.

[image: Archive Utility.app Preferences]

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not an answer to your first question/problem directly, one workaround would be to:

1. Select all of the zips that you wish to open/unzip.
2. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open all the zip files.
3. Wait for them all to complete and open the finder windows.
4. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close all Finder windows
   *(Warning, this will close other windows not generated by the unzipping too)*

Answer (score 1):

> Question: **how to configure OSX to append new files in a folder to the end of the folder (regardless of how its sorted)**, and how to configure new folders to not pop up when unzipped.

*[VxJasonxV](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/vxjasonxv) provided [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/osx-unable-to-multitask-unzipping-multiple-files/12006#12006) for the latter part of the question, so here is the first part.*

Make sure you've only checked `Arrange by…` option rather than `Keep arranged by…` option (displayed when <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed) under the `View` menu.

The Keep arranged by option  is similar to automatic sorting in Windows and will automatically sort the contents of the folder. The automatic sort cannot be omitted neither in OSX or Windows — in other ways than turning it off, that is.

For demonstration, here I zipped amg-1.png with `Arrange by… Name` set (ie. no keep):

[image: no keep]

And here is the same file zipped, but with `Keep arranged by… Name` set:

[image: keep]

Comment: Hi I' not using a mac keyboard, what is the option button?

Comment: @Charuru most probably `Alt`. I'll edit my answer, sorry for inconvenience!